# SfDataGrid and dataAdapter

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin 
is there anyway to charge SfDataGrid by Adapter , i'm trying with `grvd.ItemsSource = adapter;`
but it's not working . 
ps: when i'm using a normal gridview it's working ( `grvd.Adapter=adapter` )
but i'm trying to use SfDataGrid

```
 var grvd = FindViewById<SfDataGrid>(Resource.Id.sfDataGrid1);
                var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleExpandableListItem1);
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=45.218.171.78;Initial Catalog=DB_B2B;user=test; Password=test");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from en_cours ");
                con.Open();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                SqlDataReader sqlreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (sqlreader.Read())
                {
                    adapter.Add((string)sqlreader[0]);
                    adapter.Add((string)sqlreader[2]);

                }
                grvd.ItemsSource = adapter;

                sqlreader.Close();
                con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind only an System.Collections.IEnumerable collection as ItemsSource to the SfDataGrid.

https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/cref_files/xamarin-android/Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.Android~Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.SfDataGrid~ItemsSource.html

Refer the below documentation from Syncfusion to know how to get started with it.

https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin-android/sfdatagrid/getting-started

Refer below link for more details on DataBinding.

https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin-android/sfdatagrid/data-binding

Also, you can always contact their support for any help that your require regarding Syncfusion controls using below link.

https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/xamarin.android

Comment: thank youu , you helped me , i just wanna ask you is syncfusion free ??

Comment: Thie bellow link may help you better https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Comment: Yes Syncfusion is free if you are eligible for its community edition. Check out their site for more appropriate details regarding eligibility criteria.